# repomd.xml missing for epel-release repo

Tags: python, linux, centos, yum, epel

I've just installed the epel-release repo via this link :

> http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm

, in order to install python-pip on my CentOS 7 VM.
But after tha when I want to use yum, it gives me this error :

```
  Could not parse metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=i386 error was 
    No repomd file
```

It seems to miss the repomd.xml file in /var/cache/yum/i386/7/epel/

Does someone know how to fix that ?

Comment: Which arch are you trying to install this on,  `i386` arch or `x86_64`? I think epel doesn't support `i386` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=i386

If you download this metalink file and look inside, you will see a line like this,

`# repo = epel-7 arch = i386 error: invalid repo or arch`

and a few lines that says the following:

```
# repo=epel-7&arch=aarch64
# repo=epel-7&arch=ppc64
# repo=epel-7&arch=ppc64le
# repo=epel-7&arch=x86_64
```

AFAIK, `epel` and `CentOS-7` don't support `i386` anymore. You can still find some `i386` RPMs under CentOS-7 altarch [here](http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7.3.1611/), but that's about it.

For `epel` it provides all the source RPMs [here](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/SRPMS/), which can be used to build `i386` RPMs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Thanks for the clear explanation.